# DropDownList showing duplicate values in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdownlistfor

I have only Yes and No as my item lists in my drop down but if i select "No" 3 times then it shows in my drop down list 3 times so it is duplicating each selection i make from the drop down.  After the selection it calls stored procedure which updates the back-end to either Yes or No based on the selection.  I am confused here so please help.  thanks
Here is my ASPX code for the DD

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="My_DD" runat="server" 
              AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="ItemCompleted" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DD_Changed" 
              DataValueField="ItemCompleted">
              <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="No"></asp:ListItem>
          </asp:DropDownList>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
protected void DD_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList My_DD = (DropDownList)sender;

        this.Bind_DD();

    }   

    protected void Bind_DD()
    {

        string myVar;
        myVar= My_DD.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string ID;
        ID = Request.QueryString["ID"];
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_DD");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@myVAr", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = myVar;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ID;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

        sda.Fill(dt);
        My_DD.DataSource = dt;

        My_DD.DataBind();

    }
```

Page Load code here:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Post_ID = Page.RouteData.Values["Post_ID"] as string;

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindData();
            BindData_ActionItems();

            //load DV_New
            LoadDetailView_New();       

        }

    }
```

Comment: trying clearing your dropdownlist before you bind it again.

Comment: AppendDataBoundItems="true" my guess is to set this flag as flase, but it might be wrong

Comment: Please show your load event code.  It isn't uncommon for someone to forget to add `If(!IsPostback){}`.  If you don't have that, the code could be executed multiple times and the viewstate saves the values.

Comment: just added page_load code.  thnx

Answer (score 1):

what happens from code as i understand :
you click Yes/No and then rebind data inside the same dropdown list with values that comes from db. i don't get the error but you can try to reclear dropdownlist before re-adding the items from the db

```
protected void Bind_DD()
{

    string myVar;
    myVar= My_DD.SelectedValue.ToString();
    string ID;
    ID = Request.QueryString["ID"];
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_DD");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@My_DD", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = My_DD;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ID;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

    sda.Fill(dt);

    My_DD.Items.Clear();

    My_DD.DataSource = dt;
    My_DD.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: exactly,i re-edited the code. Try it and tell me what you got

Comment: okay that did not generate any duplicates, but it removed one of the item lists from the drop down for example, I selected No couple times but it removed the Yes item from the drop down.  thx

Comment: and Yes should be removed or not? also you add anything to dropdown on page_load?

Comment: Yes or No should always be available in the dropdow and user should be able to switch anytime they need to do so, however if I select No for ID# 89 so next time when the page loads for the ID# 89 then the selected value for the dropdown should be NO.  Initially, there is no values for Yes or NO in the rows for my table but the user has to select which values they would like to write in the rows for the corresponding IDs.  I am not adding anything in the drop down on page_load.  thanks for your time.